# Function passes test inside the package and fails from vignette (due to cpp_object_initializer)

Tags: r, package

I am writing an R package that uses `rstan` for Bayesian
sampling. ([Here](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/commit/6fd9ddf82e10b1033533d06dd06878567627de5c)
is the specific commit if you want to reproduce the issue.) I only succeed in
running a function that calls `rstan` from the vignette if I use
`library(rstan)` in the vignette, and not with a few workarounds.

#### The setup

A function in the package calls `rstan` (edited for clarity):

```r
#' @importFrom Rcpp cpp_object_initializer
#' @export
run_variational_bayes <- function(x, y, output_samples, beta_sd, stan_file) {

  n_input <- length(y)
  p <- ncol(x)

  train_dat <- list(n = n_input, p = p, x = x, y = y, beta_sd = beta_sd)

  stan_model <- rstan::stan_model(file = stan_file)

  stan_vb <- rstan::vb(object = stan_model, data = train_dat,
                 output_samples = output_samples)

  return(rstan::extract(stan_vb)$beta)
}
```

I test this function in the package:

```r
context("RStan variational Bayes model")

test_that("Rstan variational Bayes model runs", {

  german <- PosteriorBootstrap::get_german_credit_dataset()
  n_bootstrap <- 10
  prior_variance <- 100

  stan_vb_sample <- PosteriorBootstrap::run_variational_bayes(x = german$x,
                                          y = german$y,
                                          output_samples = n_bootstrap,
                                          beta_sd = sqrt(prior_variance),
                                          iter = 10)
  expect_true(nrow(stan_vb_sample) == n_bootstrap)
  expect_true(ncol(stan_vb_sample) == ncol(german$x))
})
```

The tests pass locally and on Travis, so the function works from inside the
package.

#### The problem

The vignette code works if I include `library(rstan)`:

```r
library(rstan)
prior_sd <- 10
n_bootstrap <- 1000
german <- PosteriorBootstrap::get_german_credit_dataset()
stan_vb_sample <- PosteriorBootstrap::run_variational_bayes(x = german$x,
                                                            y = german$y,
                                                            output_samples = n_bootstrap,
                                                            beta_sd = prior_sd)
dim(stan_vb_sample)
#> [1] 1000   25
```

but I see it as bad practice that the user needs to attach another package to
use my package. If I use `requireNamespace()`, building the vignette works but
the Stan model does not run:

```r
requireNamespace("PosteriorBootstrap", quietly = TRUE)
# ...
stan_vb_sample <- PosteriorBootstrap::run_variational_bayes(x = german$x,
                                                            y = german$y,
                                                            output_samples = n_bootstrap,
                                                            beta_sd = prior_sd)
#> Error in cpp_object_initializer(.self, .refClassDef, ...) : 
#>   could not find function "cpp_object_initializer"
#> failed to create the model; variational Bayes not done
#> Stan model 'bayes_logit' does not contain samples.
dim(stan_vb_sample)
#> NULL
```

Note that I used `#' @importFrom Rcpp cpp_object_initializer` in the Roxygen
comment, which should import the function that `rstan` says is missing.

#### Comparison with another package that uses `rstan`

[This package](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/blob/master/DESCRIPTION)
has similar values in `DESCRIPTION`, yet I tested that it does not require `library(rstan)` to
run `rstan`. It uses `@import Rcpp` in one function, which I tested with my
package by replacing `@importFrom Rcpp cpp_object_initializer` in front of the
function and got the same error.

#### Failed workarounds

The difference between `requireNamespace()` and `library()` is that the latter
imports the namespace of the package into the current environment. But
`rstan` does `import(Rcpp)` so that object should be available.

(1) I tried `library("PosteriorBootstrap")` in the vignette, since the
package imports that object into its namespace: I got the same error (with
`@import Rcpp` or with `@importFrom Rcpp cpp_object_initializer`).

(2) I copied that object to the environment of the function:

```r
requireNamespace("Rcpp", quietly = TRUE)

#' @import Rcpp
#' @export
run_variational_bayes <- function(x, y, output_samples, beta_sd,
                                  stan_file = get_stan_file(),
                                  iter = 10000, seed = 123, verbose = FALSE) {

  cpp_object_initializer <- Rcpp:cpp_object_initializer
  # ...
}
```

and I was surprised to get a vignette error:

```
E  creating vignettes (1.8s)
   Quitting from lines 151-157 (anpl.Rmd) 
   Error: processing vignette 'anpl.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   object 'Rcpp' not found
   Execution halted
```

#### Temporary solution

As a temporary solution, I moved the code in the function to the vignette
entirely. The vignette fails with `requireNamespace()`:

```r
requireNamespace("rstan")
#> Loading required namespace: rstan
prior_sd <- 10
n_bootstrap <- 1000
german <- PosteriorBootstrap::get_german_credit_dataset()
train_dat <- list(n = length(german$y), p = ncol(german$x), x = german$x, y = german$y, beta_sd = prior_sd)
stan_file <- PosteriorBootstrap::get_stan_file()
stan_model <- rstan::stan_model(file = stan_file)
stan_vb <- rstan::vb(object = stan_model, data = train_dat, seed = seed,
                 output_samples = n_bootstrap)
#> Error in cpp_object_initializer(.self, .refClassDef, ...) : 
#>   could not find function "cpp_object_initializer"
#> failed to create the model; variational Bayes not done
stan_vb_sample <- rstan::extract(stan_vb)$beta
#> Stan model 'bayes_logit' does not contain samples.
dim(stan_vb_sample)
#> NULL
```

and succeeds with `library(rstan)`:

```r
library("rstan")
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
# ...
stan_model <- rstan::stan_model(file = stan_file)
stan_vb <- rstan::vb(object = stan_model, data = train_dat, seed = seed,
                 output_samples = n_bootstrap)
#> Chain 1: ------------------------------------------------------------
# ...
#> Chain 1: COMPLETED.
stan_vb_sample <- rstan::extract(stan_vb)$beta
dim(stan_vb_sample)
#> [1] 1000   25
```

In moving the code out of the package, I realised that a test that uses
`library("rstan")` and calls the `rstan` package directly, e.g.

```r
context("Adaptive non-parametric learning function")
library("rstan")
# ...
test_that("Adaptive non-parametric learning with posterior samples works", {

  german <- get_german_credit_dataset()

  n_bootstrap <- 100

  # Get posterior samples
  seed <- 123
  prior_sd <- 10
  train_dat <- list(n = length(german$y), p = ncol(german$x), x = german$x,
                    y = german$y, beta_sd = prior_sd)
  stan_model <- rstan::stan_model(file = get_stan_file())
  stan_vb <- rstan::vb(object = stan_model, data = train_dat, seed = seed,
                       output_samples = n_bootstrap)
  stan_vb_sample <- rstan::extract(stan_vb)$beta
  # ...
}
```

passes the tests inside the package:

```
✔ | 24       | Adaptive non-parametric learning function [53.1 s]

══ Results ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 53.2 s

OK:       24
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

but the same test with `requireNamespace("rstan")` fails them:

```
⠋ | 21       | Adaptive non-parametric learning functionError in cpp_object_initializer(.self, .refClassDef, ...) : 
  could not find function "cpp_object_initializer"
Stan model 'bayes_logit' does not contain samples.
...
══ Results ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 51.7 s

OK:       22
Failed:   1
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

#### Conclusion

I wonder if `rstan` code is calling `cpp_object_initializer` without a
qualifier, and if it's doing that in a new environment that does not inherit the
objects from the calling environment.

I acknowledge that I did not use `rstantools` to start the package
(my employer decided to stick with the MIT license and chose not to restart the
package structure from scratch) and that I am compiling
the model at call time. I suppose that users providing their own model would
face the same errors when using `requireNamespace()` instead of `library()`.

How can I allow users to run package functions that call `rstan` without
`library(rstan)`, short of restarting the package from scratch with `rstantools`?